# How to disable server-side JavaScript on MongoDB from Java Application

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a java web application that does CRUD ops on a MongoDB Atlas instance. I want to disable server-side JavaScript for my Atlas instance from my Java web application.
What I have found out are [this](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-disable-server-side-javascript-on-mongodb-a099fc0b8f75) and [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#javascript) which basically say that I need to either alter the `mongod.conf` file or use the command line args `--noscripting` on `mongod` command. But I want to accomplish this using my Java web application when the web app starts.

**Does the MongoDB java driver provide a mechanism to achieve this?**
**Are there any alternate ways to get this done?**

Note: I do not want to pass `mongod` command from my web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the MongoDB java driver provide a mechanism to achieve this?

The option to enable or disable server-side JavaScript can only be set in the MongoDB server configuration on startup; it is not possible to change via a driver or runtime API call.

Since MongoDB Atlas is a managed service, end users do not have direct access to MongoDB server configuration and are limited to options exposed via the admin UI.

MongoDB Atlas does not currently allow configuring the [`security.javascriptEnabled`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.javascriptEnabled) value: server-side JavaScript execution is [disabled for free/shared clusters](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/index.html) (M0, M2, M5) and enabled for M10+ clusters.

> Are there any alternate ways to get this done?

If you have an M10+ MongoDB Atlas cluster (which currently has JavaScript execution enabled by default) you can [open a support case](https://cloud.mongodb.com/support) and ask if it would be possible to disable server-side JavaScript for your cluster. Customer requests/feedback are one signal that would encourage either changing the default value in MongoDB Atlas or making it configurable via UI.

Comment: I read that disabling the JavaScript engine on the server-side can protect against NoSQL injections and hence I wanted to know. I am using the M0 free cluster. So this resolves my current situation.Thank You.